# Parse text file and store fields in hash table in Perl

Tags: perl, file, parsing, hashtable

i have a problem with my perl script which read a text file and store the first field separated by a tabulation.

Here an example:
texte input file :

```
@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers tout le    1   0.000012706627117
a a pour les ressortissants des nouveaux états  1   0.000006796917515
a abandonné dès l abord avec dilettantisme l    1   0.000009584625169
a abandonné la culture du lin à fibres  1   0.000009718010335
a abandonné le secteur de la pêche aux  1   0.000006983488644
```

So the script must store the first fields from each line and store them in a hash table here: '@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers tout le', 'a a pour les ressortissants des nouveaux états', 'a abandonné dès l abord avec dilettantisme', 'a abandonné la culture du lin à fibres', 'a abandonné le secteur de la pêche aux'.

Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# use strict;

my %hash = ();

open (my $fh,"<", "tst") or die "Can't open the file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh>){

chomp ($line);

my ($key)=split("\t", $line);

my $val;

$hash{$key} =$val;

}

print "\n";

while ( my ($key, $val) = each(%hash) ) {

print "$key => $val\n";

  }
```

The problem is that this script does not work :(  Any idea please?

Comment: Since you don't supply a value for `$val`, your hash will store the keys but `undef` for the values, which makes for noisy printing.  You should uncomment `use strict;`.  What are you expecting for the values — the other values in the line (and if so, as a single string or as an array of values)?

Answer (score 1):

This simple (moderately simple) adaptation of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = ();
my $file = "tst";

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh>)
{
    chomp ($line);
    my($key, $count, $number) = split("\t", $line);
    $hash{$key} = [ $count, $number ];
}

while (my($key, $val) = each(%hash))
{
    print "$key => @{$val}\n";
}
```

given the input file:

```
@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers tout le       1       0.000012706627117
a a pour les ressortissants des nouveaux états    1       0.000006796917515
a abandonné dès l abord avec dilettantisme l      1       0.000009584625169
a abandonné la culture du lin à fibres    1       0.000009718010335
a abandonné le secteur de la pêche aux    1       0.000006983488644
```

(where multiple blanks represent a tab in the file, gives the output:

```
a a pour les ressortissants des nouveaux états => 1 0.000006796917515
@ ries bibliothèques électroniques à travers tout le => 1 0.000012706627117
a abandonné la culture du lin à fibres => 1 0.000009718010335
a abandonné dès l abord avec dilettantisme l => 1 0.000009584625169
a abandonné le secteur de la pêche aux => 1 0.000006983488644
```

If that's not what you're after, maybe you need to specify what value should be stored with each key.

The `my($key, $count, $number)` part saves three fields per line into the named variables.  The line:

```
$hash{$key} = [ $count, $number ];
```

creates a hash entry with the string `$key` storing an array reference, where the array contains two values, `$count` and `$number`.  And the line

```
print "$key => @{$val}\n";
```

prints the array referenced by `$val`.

---

The requirements are still unclear, but apparently, only the key needs to be stored.  It is not clear whether it is sufficient to store it in an array, or whether it must be stored in a hash.

#### Array

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @array = ();
my $file = "tst";

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh>)
{
    chomp ($line);
    my($key) = split("\t", $line);
    push @array, $key;
}

foreach my $key (@array)
{
    print "$key\n";
}
```

#### Hash

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my %hash = ();
my $file = "tst";

open (my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open the file $file: ";

while (my $line =<$fh>)
{
    chomp ($line);
    my($key) = split("\t", $line);
    $hash{$key} = 1;
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash)
{
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, but i want to store only "a a pour les ressortissants des nouveaux états"

Comment: What do you want as the key, or the value?  Or do you want the string stored as the value for the key?  You can always do `$hash{$key} = 1;` to indicate that the key exists.  You can use `undef` if you prefer...but then you don't want to print the `$val` because it doesn't convey any information.

Comment: Why not just push the values into an @array if you only want the first field input?