# store txt data in hash table

Tags: perl

I have a table (txt) which I want to read into perl and store the different columns in individual hashes with the same keys. In detail the table looks something like this:

(first column : ID, 
second column: parents,
third column: gender, 
fourth column: affection_status)

A1  0   m   no

A2  0   f   no

A3  A1A2    m   no

A4  A1A2    f   yes

A5  A1A2    f   yes

B1  0   m   no

I read old threads in stackoverflow ( [Parse text file and store fields in hash table in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160468/parse-text-file-and-store-fields-in-hash-table-in-perl)) and came up with this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;

my %pedigree= ();
my $file = "pedigree.txt";

open (pedigree,'<','pedigree.txt') or die ("Cannot open file");

while (<pedigree>) { 
  chomp;  
  my ($ID,$parents,$gender,$affection_status)=split /\t/; 
  $pedigree{$ID} = [$parents, $gender, $affection_status];

};
```

what I want to do is to create hashes (parents, gender, affection_status that all have the same keys (ID). I then want to see to the individual values when entering the key:

```
print "Please enter patient ID: "; #user input required: patient ID
chomp(my $ID = <STDIN>);

print "$ID gender: $pedigree{gender}{$ID}\n 
$ID affected: $pedigree{affection_status}{$ID}\n  
$ID parents: $pedigree{parents}{$ID} \n" ;
```

However when I run this, I get no output. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%pedigree` should be populated in the same way you want to read from it,

```
my @cols = qw(parents gender affection_status);
while (<pedigree>) {
  chomp;
  my ($ID, @arr) = split /\t/; 
  $pedigree{ $cols[$_] }{$ID} = $arr[$_] for 0 .. $#cols;
}
```

Comment: Wow that was quick:-) Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Pustefix you can also change ouput, `$pedigree{$ID}[1]` would be for gender